# Upgrade "react-jss" from v8 to v10

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jss

I tried upgrading react-jss to V10.6.0 and i got this error in node_modules:
[Unexpected token, expected ","](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY44P.png)

```
    ./node_modules/react-jss/src/jss.js
SyntaxError: C:\ .....\node_modules\react-jss\src\jss.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (2:21)

> 2 | import {create, type Jss} from 'jss'
    |                      ^
  3 | import preset from 'jss-preset-default'
  4 | 
  5 | const jss: Jss = create(preset())
```

Notice that my project is class component based and i'm using node v12.14.1.

Comment: what version of node are you using? does this library require a newer version?

Comment: i'm using v12.14.1 and i'm currently trying to find if the library require a new version

Comment: it looks like it requires flow

Comment: sadly that does remove the red warnings in vscode but i still got a failed to compile.